# Artin's proof of the order of $\mathbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As Ben suggested in [my earlier question on the subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52537/order-of-mathbbzi-abi), I looked at Artin's proof that $\left|\cdot\right|^2$ is a "size function" which makes $\mathbb Z [i]$ into a Euclidean domain. To quote page 398:

> We divide the complex number b by a: $b=aw$, where $w=x+yi$ a complex number, not necessarily a Gauss integer. The we choose the nearest Gauss integer point $(m,n)$ to $(x,y)$, writing $x=m+x_0,y=n+y_0$, where m,n are integers and $x_0,y_0$ real numbers such that $-1/2\leq x_0,y_0<1/2$. Then $(m+ni)a$ is the required point of $Ra$. For, $\left|x_0 + y_0i\right|^2<1/2$ and $|b-(m+ni)a|^2=|a(x_0+y_0i)|^2<\frac{1}{2}|a|^2$.

I have two questions:

1. I assume he's using the notation $\left|a+bi\right|=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. If so, it seems like $\left|x_0 + y_0i\right|^2<1/2$ is not always true since $\left|(-1/2)+(-1/2)i\right|^2=1/2$
2. He never uses the identity $i^2=-1$, so it seems like this proof could be expanded to all rings $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2 + a)$, or indeed anything which has a vectorspace-like structure like $\mathbb Z^2$. But I remember hearing that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not Euclidean - why does this proof fail for $x^2 = -5$?

---

*EDIT*: $\sqrt{-5}\approx 2.2i$ so we can write for example $3i \approx 1.3\sqrt{-5}$. By my understanding, $y_0=.3$ here and the norm $|0+.3|=0^2+.3^2$ is less than one. Furthermore, every $x_0,y_0$ is less than $1/2$, so this norm will always be less than 1, which is all we need.

Why doesn't this show that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is Euclidean?

Comment: For (1): The norm in number theory is different. For Gaussian integers it is $a^2+b^2$.  If one took the square root, norm would be usually irrational, and people in number theory are very rational.

Comment: For(2): If you look at the ring $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, then the imaginary parts of the elements of the ring are integer multiples of $\sqrt5$ as opposed to (rational) integers as here. Therefore the `error' term $y_0$ may be as large as $\sqrt{5}/2>1$, and this approach to getting a Euclidean algorithm fails.

Comment: I looked at the actual passage! Artin is using $|x+yi|$ in its standard complex variable sense, and there is a typo as pointed out by the OP. There is no problem, we don't need $\lt 1/2$ anyway to push through the Gaussian version of the Division Algorithm, $\lt 1$ is good enough. But earlier comment still (mostly) stands.

Comment: @Jyrki: but isn't $y_0=y-\lfloor y \rfloor$ (or $\lceil y \rceil - y$) and hence always less than one?

Comment: @Xodarap: In that case you are trying to find a point of the form $m+in\sqrt{5}$ that is as close to $w=x+iy$ as possible. The error will be $y_0=y-\sqrt5\lfloor(y/\sqrt5)\rfloor$ or $y_0=\sqrt5 \lceil(y/\sqrt5)\rceil-y$. All depending whether the integer $n$ is below or above $y/\sqrt5$.

Comment: @Jyrki: As an example: $6i=(1.2)5i$. I thought $y_0=.2$ - you are saying $y_0 = (.2)5i$?

Comment: @Xodarap: No. If $w=6i$, then the closest element of the ring $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is $3\sqrt5 i$, so $y_0=(3\sqrt{5}-6)$. You are no longer looking for the closest Gaussian integer.

Comment: @Xodarap: It is possible that we are normalizing things differently. I am looking at the usual distance from an arbitrary complex number $w$ to the closest point of the ring. Look at Paul's answer, too. His normalization along the imaginary axis (if you fix his typo and think in terms of $\sqrt{-5}$) is different from mine in the sense that he scales it differently. But he compensates for this difference by studying the correct norm $|a+b\sqrt{-5}|^2=a^2+5b^2$, so in the end Paul and I get the same results.

Comment: @Jyrki: could you look at my edit?

Comment: @Xodarap: $|x_0+y_0\sqrt{-5}|^2=x_0^2+5y_0^2$. If here $x_0=y_0=0.5$, then $x_0^2+5y_0^2=1.25>1$. See the answer by Paul Garrett.

Comment: @Jyrki: I'm defining the norm differently than Paul. Artin places no restrictions on the norm function, so it seems like this is a legitimate thing to do.

Comment: Without saying "because $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ does not have unique factorization" it seems like it would be very hard to show that there is no norm. If you just want to show that $N(a + b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5b^2$ is not a norm, I think we can do something for you.

Comment: @Xodarap: Artin does place one important restriction on the norm: the norm should be multiplicative. IOW for all complex numbers $w,z\in\mathbf{C}$ you should have $|zw|=|z|\cdot |w|$. This is used in the equation $|a(x_0+iy_0)|^2=|a|^2|x_0+iy_0|^2\le\frac12|a|^2$. You **MUST** use the norm $|x+y\sqrt{-5}|=x^2+5y^2$. Otherwise the norm is not multiplicative. I don't have access to the text, but whatever the 'size'-function is called, surely it must be multiplicative.

Comment: @Jyrki It doesn't seem like he requires it, at least in the first edition.

Comment: Jyrki, @Dylan: Thanks! I guess my question could've been phrased better but I think I understand now.

Comment: If we write $N(x+iy)$ instead of $|x+iy|^2$ for any which function we please, how do we deduce $$N(a(x_0+iy_0))=N(a)N(x_0+iy_0)\le \frac12 N(a)$$ without $N$ being multiplicative???? The equality here. That is a key to the argument, surely.

Comment: But sorry about contributing to the confusion. I should have asked for Xodarap's definition of $|\cdot|$ to start with, because that's were the differences were coming from.

Comment: @Xodarap: Looks like you're taken care of, but I'll add 2 things: 1) The geometry at the heart of Artin's proof: a unit square is completely covered by unit discs centered at its corners; the multiples of (a+bi) form a square lattice; every Gaussian integer is in one of the squares, so it is less than |a+bi| away from one of the corners, i.e. from a multiple of a+bi. On the other hand, if you put unit discs at the corners of a 1 by $\sqrt{5}$ rectangle, they leave a little patch in the middle uncovered, and it is precisely this patch that jams up the proof.

Comment: And 2) working through the rest of Artin Ch. 11 is really going to put this all in perspective. Esp. sections 6 and 7, but if you have time to work through the whole chapter you will feel like you understand all of this very deeply. (This was my experience.)

Comment: @Ben: Ah cool! "if you put unit discs at the corners of a 1 by $\sqrt{5}$ rectangle, they leave a little patch in the middle uncovered" - this is a very intuitive way of understanding it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the normalizations, the requirement of "Euclidean" is that the remainder is strictly smaller than the divisor. Thus, in the highlighted paragraph above, the *necessary* conclusion is simply that the norm of the leftoever be strictly smaller than the divisor, not than *half* the size of the divisor.

In the case of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$, the analogous leftover $a+b\sqrt{5}$ again has $|a|,|b|\le 1/2$, but the usual complex absolute value, squared or not, is $(1/2)^2+5(1/2)^2=6/4>1$. Taking a square root or squaring or not... does not affect the crucial issue of whether it's $<1$ or not.

Some examples of computations about Euclidean-ness of rings of alg integers are in  [my notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/01.pdf) , and many other places on the internet, I'm sure.

Edit: in response to further query... in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, the leftovers are $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ with $|a|,|b|\le 1/2$. The norm (-squared) is
$a^2+5b^2\le (1/4)+5(1/4)=6/4>1$. In the "EDIT" in the query, yes, there is a particular example where the norm is $<1$. Ok, but that doesn't imply that *all* leftovers are $<1$. Yes, every $x_0,y_0$ are at most $1/2$ in size, but that's *without* the "5"! $|x_0+y_0\sqrt{-5}|^2=x_0^2+5y_0^2$.

Comment: Could you look at my edit? I still don't think I understand.

Comment: Nevermind, I think the problem was that I didn't realize $|ab|$ must be $|a||b|$.

Comment: Ah. Indeed! ...