# Describe the rings: a) $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2 - 3, 2x + 4)$, b) $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ (2 + i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Describe each of following the rings:

a) $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2 - 3, 2x + 4)$

b) $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ (2 + i)$

a) Well, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients and $(x^2 - 3, 2x + 4)$  is the ideal generated by two polynomials. I know that 
$\mathbb Z[x] / (x^2 - 3, 2x + 4) = \{ r + (x^2 - 3, 2x + 4) : r \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \}$

b) I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the set of all polynomials with the complex number $i$ as its variable. $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ (2 + i) = \{ r + (2 + i) : r \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \}$.

I already know that b) is $\mathbb Z$ modulo 5. What would a) be?

Comment: b) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455157/cosets-modulo-2i-in-mathbbzi

Comment: Thanks, how would I approach a)?

Answer (score 5):

b) The link didn't contain what I consider the cleanest approach to this problem, and this is a good warm-up for a), so I thought I'd answer it again.  The trick is to think of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$.  Then we can compute the quotient in two steps: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,x+2) = \mathbb{Z}/((-2)^2+1) = \mathbb{Z}/(5)$.

a) We can write $(x^2-3,2x+4) = (x^2-3,2x+4,2x^2-6)=(x^2-3,2x+4,(-4)x-6)$ $=(x^2-3,2x+4,4x+6-2(2x+4))$ $=(x^2-3,2x+4,-2) = (x^2+1,2)$.  You can rewrite this in terms of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if you like, but I think it's better to make the substitution $y=x+1$ to get the lovely expression $\mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2)$.

Hopefully this was useful, and hopefully you know that your grader probably also uses StackExchange and cares whether you properly cite your sources.

Comment: b) is a particular case of $\mathbb Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong\mathbb Z/(a^2+b^2)$ when $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Your proof repeats the general proof given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52537/order-of-some-quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers) by Gone.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are obtaining the equalities in part (a)?

Comment: Linear combinations.  Let me know if there's one in particular you're having trouble with.