# Given L is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, and write $\mathbb{Z}^3/L$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**Let $L \subset Z$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by the elements $(−1, −1, 4)$, $(2, 4, 0)$ and $(3, 3, 8)$.**

**Write $\mathbb{Z}^3/L$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups.**

Since L is spanned by $(-1,-1,4),(2,4,0)$, and $(3, 3, 8)$, and they are linear independent, I think L = $\mathbb{Z}^3$, but I am not sure about it. So I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me to figure it out! Thank you!

Comment: Here are some relevant links: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m/1548318#1548318), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group/1604950#1604950) and [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422919/suggestions-for-computing-mathbbzi3-k-where-k-langle1-2-1-0-0-5/1423230#1423230).

Comment: The short answer is to compute the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of the matrix whose columns are these vectors.

Comment: Just because they are linearly independent does not mean that you can associate $L$ to $\Bbb Z^3$. Could you somehow get $(1,0,0)$ from integer linear combinations? Obviously this is the case with rational linear combinations, but need not be the case for _integer_ linear combinations.

Comment: So I got the Smith normal form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&20\end{pmatrix}$. Is it correct? Then the answer should be $\frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}\oplus 2\mathbb{Z} \oplus 20 \mathbb{Z}} = \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Comment: @NoboruHayashi You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910883/