# Write $\mathbb{Z}^3/L$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $L\subset \mathbb{Z}$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by the elements $(-1,-1,4),(2,4,0),(3,3,8)$. Write $\mathbb{Z}^3/L$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups.

I've tried creating a matrix and row reducing, finding the null space of the matrix, but it doesn't seem to produce an obvious answer.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form?

Comment: Questions very similar to this one have been asked many times.  Here are a few: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group/1604950#1604950), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422919/suggestions-for-computing-mathbbzi3-k-where-k-langle1-2-1-0-0-5/1423230#1423230), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m/1548318#1548318).