# How do you write this module as a direct sum of cyclic modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let M be the module over Z [i] generated by elements x, y whose relations are determined by $(1+i)x+(2-i)y=0$ and $3x+5y=0$. How can one write M as a direct sum of cyclic modules?

Comment: Hey, and welcome to M.SE! To help you, it is helpful to know what you have tried, what your background is (e.g., are you comfortable with the notion of direct sum and cyclic module?), and what your process of thinking was when you  approached this question.

Comment: @Luke, I'm learning modules for the first time. So that, when I think of a module I'm always with the generalization of a vector space. When I think of direct sum I always think on the linear combination of linearly independent generators of subspaces. But I don't know how can I relate this thinking with that question.

Comment: @MikeHawk you seem to have confused the title field for the tags field. I changed the title to be more useful. You should do something like that next time. Remember, the goal is to be informative and searchable.  If you don’t, well, you’ll probably find out what the consequences are. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @rschwieb

Comment: Similar to these: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422919/suggestions-for-computing-mathbbzi3-k-where-k-langle1-2-1-0-0-5/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586353/how-to-recognize-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-as-a-product-of-cyclic-group), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546751/finding-an-explicit-isomorphism-from-mathbbz4-h-to-mathbbz-oplus-m)

Comment: Thanks @André3000, but could you answer to the question to give me an insight?