# Homomorphic images of Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Let $x=a+bi$ be an arbitrary Gaussian integer and consider the qoutient ring $S := \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{(x)}$. I know that the number of elements of $S$ is equal to $a^2 + b^2$. Is it true that $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{a^2+b^2}$ (as rings)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes I think the answer is negative because the ideal generated by 3 is maximal but $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is not a field. Am I correct !?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and I like your thinking.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks. Is there a known characterization of maximal ideals of Gaussian integers ?

Comment: Depending on your knowledge of ring theory; the Gaussian integers are a principal ideal domain, so its maximal ideals are precisely its nonzero prime ideals, which are the ideals generated by prime elements. The Gaussian primes the (normal) primes $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$, and the Gaussian integers $a+bi$ with $a^2+b^2=p$, with $p$ a (normal) prime. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Gaussian_primes) gives a decent overview.

Comment: A useful observation in this context is that the inclusion $f:\ \Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a ring homomorphism, so for every prime ideal $I\subset\Bbb{Z}[i]$ also $f^{-1}(I)=I\cap\Bbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal, so $I$ contains a prime number $p$. Because all ideals in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ are principal ideals there is some Gaussian integer $a+bi$ such that $I=(a+bi)$, and $p\in I$ implies that $a+bi$ divides $p$. This line of reasoning works for many rings of the form $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Similar questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373073/quotient-rings-of-gaussian-integers), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52537/order-of-some-quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers). The claim is true if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider Gaussian integers that are (normal) integers.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?